# xml parsing is faster in C/C++ or Java?

Tags: java, c++, c, xml

I need to parse XML either in C/C++ or Java.

Which one is fast?

I think SAX parser will be ok with java

Pl. help

Comment: This question assumes that there is exactly one Java XML parser and exactly one C or C++ XML parser. There are lots for _both_. Most important of all, why would it matter? Are you really going to choose the language you code in based on whether its XML parser is faster?

Comment: There are many XML parsers available in C/C++ and Java.  They are ALL likely fast enough for you.  So unless you got a very specific performance goal in mind, choose the language, runtime, and XML library that is 1) easiest to use, 2) best suits your experience, and 3) fits with project design.  Prototype to make sure it meets expected performance goals. My gut feeling is that you'll find Java and it's XML DOM parser easiest to consume and use (and will be fast enough).

Comment: @ Nicol Bolas - yes, i need to choose language on which will parse XML as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally C++ is compiled to native code while java is compiled to byte code and then is interpreted at runtime. Therefore C++ code should theoretically run fater.

But due to automatic memory management and other good features java development is much easier and faster. The big question is do you really ned some extraordinal performance requirements here? If not, implement everything in java. If you do have such requirements think about other options.

And BTW, why SAX? It is the hardest (and really fastest) whay to parse XML. Did you problably think about easier ways like JAXB? It requires 1% of efforts (relatively to SAX).

Answer (score 0):

SAX parser is ok with Java.

But it is not connected to the Java/C++ performance comparison. SAX parsers are faster than DOM ones. But C++ and Java both have XML parsers for SAX and DOM.

Comment: and which one is faster between the C++ SAX/DOM and Java SAX/DOM, just curious too :D

Comment: @SAFAD: _Which_ C++ SAX/DOM parser and _which_ Java SAX/DOM parser? There are quite a few for both.

Comment: You may find [XML parser benchmarks](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2007/05/09/xml-parser-benchmarks-part-1.html) in google and [select a suitable](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2007/05/16/xml-parser-benchmarks-part-2.html) one for your purpose.

Comment: here you see a comparison on SAX between C(++) and Java on the same implementation (xerces/Apache): [xerces/Java/C++](https://github.com/cdoyen/xmlclean/tree/master/benchmark); you see, the Java-Implementation SAXParserFactory [based on xerces](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html) works a little bit faster than the "original" C++ implementation [xercesc](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/)